# Hide layer names in layer group in GeoServer vector tile response

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles

I am trying to setup vector tiles in Geoserver.

I have two layers which I have added to an *opaque* `layer group`:

[image]

When I request data from Geoserver as vector tiles I get a file with two layers: `tiger_roads` and `tasmania_roads`.

Is it possible to change a setting somewhere in Geoserver so that the response I get from Geoserver contains a single layer with the name of the layer group?

*I know that this requires the two layers to have matching attributes even though this is not the case in the illustration above.*

---

In this post I have made a very simple mock-up to try to explain my problem, but in my real-world case I have pre-generalised data in several scales which in Geoserver is styled so that only one of the pre-generalised layers are shown any zoom level. I would like the client to only receive layer group names and not the name of the individual scale-layers contained within the layer groups.